# Intercepting D-bus method returns

Tags: python, dbus

I'm attempting to write a Python script which intercepts D-bus method calls to a particular interface. However, I also need to intercept the corresponding method returns. I understand how to intercept the method calls in Python (using add_signal_receiver) but am not sure how to intercept the method returns.

Below are examples of the method calls and returns I'm attempting to intercept, captured using dbus-monitor.

```
method call sender=:1.32 -> dest=com.nokia.HildonSVNotificationDaemon serial=694 path=/com/nokia/HildonSVNotificationDaemon; interface=com.nokia.HildonSVNotificationDaemon; member=PlayEvent
array [
    dict entry(
        string  "urgency"
        variant byte    1
    )
    dict entry(
        string  "vibra"
        variant string  "PatternIncomingMessage"
    )
    dict entry(
        string  "sound-file"
        variant string  "messaging_and_title_3"
    )
    dict entry(
        string  "category"
        variant string  "sms-message"
    )
    dict entry(
        string  "persistent"
        variant byte    1
    )
    dict entry(
        string  "time"
        variant int64   1363190279
    )
]
string  ":1.25"

method return sender=:1.21 -> dest=1.32 reply_serial=694
int32 <ID VALUE>
```